# Push a side view controller

Tags: ios, menu, viewcontroller

I am a bit new in iOS programming. I want to add view controllers in side view when click on the menu button as many apps already have. I searched in net and found 2 APIs one is PPReavealSideViewController and other is SWReavelSideController. but i don't know how to use. I downloaded the Sample project of PPReavealSideViewController but it is showing many errors. please help me I have many questions in my mind..

1. Which one is better to use PPReavealSideViewController or SWReavelSideController?
2. Is there any other way to achieve my target??

I am uplaoding a image, please help me

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use step-by-step tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/32054/how-to-create-a-slide-out-navigation-like-facebook-and-path

PPReavealSideViewController or SWReavelSideController are good but always nice to do it yourself

Comment: In that tutorial they are adding row in side view but i want to add view controller in each row.